# how to find git merge commits which merges into current branch

Tags: git, web-deployment, git-merge, git-flow, git-log

At my company we are using [git flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) to manage the development of a number of sites.
All of these sites are forks of a base repo. It is easy enough to update the sites with updates from the upstream project.
But updating the base projects with features from the sites is giving me some headaches.

Each site has its own repository as origin and the base as a profile remote.

All the common stuff that these sites share are located under one directory, and we could properly use git subtrees, but we currently do not.

Currently I check out the develop branch from profile and checkout the shared directory from the local master, commit and push to profile/develop. This squashes all features into one commit.

What I would like to do is: pull individual features from the different sites into profile/develop.

The problem is: when features are tested, publish on the site and ready to be merged upstream, the feature is already merged into master by git flow, at this point.

I have not been able to find a way of finding already merged in features in the git history of the local sites.

I have come up with a script which can tell me the merge commits that bring in stuff to the current branch:

```
git log --decorate --graph  --all|grep --before-context=1 --after-context=4 "^|\\\\"|grep ^\*|awk '{for(i=1; i <= NF; i++){if($i ~ /commit/){com = i + 1;print $com}}}'
```

When I run this this command in the local develop branch I can do a format-path on the different merges, and do a more granular update of the profile.

Could anybody please show me a more correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to find merge commits which merges into the current branch you can do

```
git log --merges
```

Comment: git log --merges Show all existing merge commits in the branch. I would like to only see the commits that merges directly into the current branch - like a feature branch being merged into develop.

Comment: @freeduck I'm afraid I don't quite understand. What merge commits do not 'merge directly into the current branch'?

Comment: If somebody is working in a feature branch and merges in platform (see my initial question) and then subsequently merges the feature into develop, then both merge commits will show up in the output of: git log --merges. I am only interested in the feature merge.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?